# How to hide .php or .html extension

Tags: php, .htaccess

I have this code in my `.htaccess` file which hide all the `.php` or `.html` extension but it does not take `index.php` or `index.html` by default.

```
 #Alternate default index pagesDirectoryIndex first.html index.htm index.html index.php
 RewriteEngine On
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
 RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
 RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.html [NC,L]
```

Its gives the error like this

```
The requested URL /example.com/aman/.php was not found on this server.
```

In `aman` folder I have an `index.php` file which it doesnot take by default.

Can anyone help me to fix this error?

Comment: can you add screenshot its working perfect in my system

Comment: Perhaps you could accept my answer on this? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't work that way. It *adds* `.php` internally, it doesn't *remove it*. Why would you want just `.php` to work anyway? Do you mean `example.com/aman/index`? That should work.

But just use:

```
example.com/aman/
```

If you're not getting index.php served on that then add something like this to your .htaccess:

```
DirectoryIndex index.php index.html index.htm
```

See [DirectoryIndex](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_dir.html#directoryindex). You've actually commented it out just above your rules which seems to be your problem. Looks like you just need to change that first line to be on two lines:

```
#Alternate default index pages
DirectoryIndex first.html index.htm index.html index.php
```

Also dots/periods do not need to be escaped in character classes, so change your rules to:

```
RewriteRule ^([^.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^([^.]+)$ $1.html [NC,L]
```